# Dirac spinor manipulation

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

I'm trying to simplify the following relationship as much as possible:
$$\partial_\mu\bar\psi[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]\psi$$
where $\psi$ satisfies the dirac equation.

Using the fact that $[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu] = 2\eta^{\mu\nu} - 2\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^\mu$ I have that:
$$\partial_\mu\bar\psi[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]\psi = 2\partial_\mu\bar\psi(\eta^{\mu\nu} - \gamma^{\nu}\gamma^\mu)\psi = 2\partial^\nu\bar\psi\psi - 2\partial_\mu\bar\psi\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu\psi $$
can this expression be further developed using gamma matrices?

Comment: That commutator is usually just denoted as $\sigma^{\mu\nu}$ (up to a multiplicative factor) as in [this](https://sites.ualberta.ca/~gingrich/courses/phys512/node56.html) description of Dirac bilinears. So it is usually kept manifestly antisymmetric and not normally turned into your unsymmetric form.